# how to iterate objects in list and that list in objects and that objects in list

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var timeslots = [
    {
        "details": [{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/16"
        },
        {
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/26"
        }],
        "time": "10:30 AM",
        "status": "Booked"
    },
    {
        "details": [{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/26"
        },{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/26"
        }],
        "time": "11:30 AM",
        "status": "Booked"
    },
    {
        "details": [{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/16"
        },{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/23"
        }],
        "time": "12:30 PM",
        "status": "Booked"
    },
    {
        "details": [{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/16"
        },{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"navee@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/16"
        }],
        "time": "02:30 PM",
        "status": "Booked"
    },
    {
        "details": [{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/16"
        },{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/16"
        }],
        "time": "03:30 PM",
        "status": "Booked"
    },
    {
        "details": [{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveeni@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/16"
        },{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/16"
        }],
        "time": "04:30 PM",
        "status": "Booked"
    },
    {
        "details": [{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/16"
        },{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/16"
        }],
        "time": "05:30 PM",
        "status": "Booked"
    }
]
```

**I have time slots like 09:00 am --09:00 pm, based on today's date I need to iterate the list of objects and i need to remove the previous date object respectively in nodejs, javascript**

> SO please help me with this
>
> Expected output

```
var date ="23/12/2019"
var timeslots = [
    {
        "details": [
        {
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/26"
        }],
        "time": "10:30 AM",
        "status": "Booked"
    },
    {
        "details": [{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveeni@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/26"
        },{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/26"
        }],
        "time": "11:30 AM",
        "status": "Booked"
    },
    {
        "details": [{
            "name":"naveen",
            "email":"naveen@gmail.com",
            "date":"2019/12/23"
        }],
        "time": "12:30 PM",
        "status": "Booked"
    },
    {
        "details": [],
        "time": "02:30 PM",
        "status": "Booked"
    },
    {
        "details": [],
        "time": "03:30 PM",
        "status": "Booked"
    },
    {
        "details": [],
        "time": "04:30 PM",
        "status": "Booked"
    },
    {
        "details": [],
        "time": "05:30 PM",
        "status": "Booked"
    }
]
```

> how can I iterate this

**I have time slots like 09:00 am --09:00 pm, based on today's date I need to iterate the list of objects and I need to remove the previous date object respectively in nodejs, javascript**

> SO please help me with this

---

### From comments below

```js
timeslots.time.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(value.time);
  value.details.forEach(function(model) {
    console.log(value.details);
    value.date.forEach(function(date) {
      console.log(value.date)
    })
  });
});

for (var i = 0; i < timeslots.length; i++) {
  if (timeslots[i].details[i].date < today) {
    list.push(timeslots[i].details[i].date)
  }
}
slots.reduceRight(function(acc, obj, idx) {
  if (list.indexOf(obj.date) > -1) slots.splice(idx, 1);
}, 0);
```

Comment: Have you got any code showing what you've tried so far?

Comment: `timeslots.time.forEach(function (value) {`
     ` console.log(value.time);`
    `  value.details.forEach(function (model) {`
       ` console.log(value.details);`
       ` value.date.forEach(function (date){`
        `    console.log(value.date)`
   `     })`
  `    });`
   ` });`

Comment: `for(var i =0;i<timeslots.length;i++){
    if(timeslots[i].details[i].date<today){
        list.push(
            timeslots[i].details[i].date
        )
    }  
}
slots.reduceRight(function(acc, obj, idx) {
    if (list.indexOf(obj.date) > -1)
        slots.splice(idx,1);
}, 0);`

Comment: I tried this two@CameronDowner

Answer (score 0):

I looked through your code and there are a couple of things that are incorrect and that can be improved.

```
var date ="23/12/2019" // string needs to be "2019/12/23" to be parsed by 'Date'
for (var i = 0; i < timeslots.length; i++) { // can be replaced with map
  if (timeslots[i].details[i].date < today) { // this is comparing strings, not dates
    list.push(timeslots[i].details[i].date) // can be replaced by filter on details
  }
}
```

I've converted your code using the things I've seen:

```
const today = "2019/12/23";

const timeslots = [...]

const answer = timeslots.map(timeSlot => {
    return {
        ...timeSlot, // this is called the spread operator
        details: timeSlot.details.filter(detail => {
            return new Date(detail.date).getTime() >= new Date(today).getTime()
        })
    }
})
```

We `map` the `timeslots` to a new object, copying the existing proerties across using the spread operator.

We then override the details property, by having it beneath in the object declaration, with a filtered version of the array.

We are filtering based on the `getTime` result of the parsed date strings. `getTime` returns the epoch timestamp of the `Date` object. This makes our comparison easier because they are just numbers.

Comment: I really appreciate you@Cameron Downer, I will rectify my mistakes and i will follow your code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can think about your problem as such: *(1)* You want to remove all details that are older than a specific date and *(2)* then you want to remove all timeslots that don't have any details left.

Consider using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It's powerful for data processing once you wrap your head around it. Here is how you could solve your issue with it:

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const prune = (date, input) => {
  const jsDate = new Date(date);
  const logic = {
    '[*].details': (value) => value.length === 0,
    '[*].details[*].date': (value) => jsDate > new Date(value)
  };
  return objectScan(Object.keys(logic), {
    rtn: 'bool',
    filterFn: ({ matchedBy, value, gparent, gproperty }) => {
      if (matchedBy.some((n) => logic[n](value))) {
        gparent.splice(gproperty, 1);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  })(input);
};

const timeslots = [ { details: [ { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/16' }, { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/26' } ], time: '10:30 AM', status: 'Booked' }, { details: [ { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/26' }, { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/26' } ], time: '11:30 AM', status: 'Booked' }, { details: [ { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/16' }, { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/23' } ], time: '12:30 PM', status: 'Booked' }, { details: [ { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/16' }, { name: 'naveen', email: 'navee@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/16' } ], time: '02:30 PM', status: 'Booked' }, { details: [ { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/16' }, { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/16' } ], time: '03:30 PM', status: 'Booked' }, { details: [ { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveeni@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/16' }, { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/16' } ], time: '04:30 PM', status: 'Booked' }, { details: [ { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/16' }, { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/16' } ], time: '05:30 PM', status: 'Booked' } ];

console.log(prune('2019/12/23', timeslots)); // return true iff changes made
// => true
console.log(timeslots);
// => [ { details: [ { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/26' } ], time: '10:30 AM', status: 'Booked' }, { details: [ { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/26' }, { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/26' } ], time: '11:30 AM', status: 'Booked' }, { details: [ { name: 'naveen', email: 'naveen@gmail.com', date: '2019/12/23' } ], time: '12:30 PM', status: 'Booked' } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@16.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)